# manipular excel en python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Estoy actualizando una consulta de un fichero Excel desde Python. Hasta aquí es correcto.
Sin embargo, el fichero actualizado se está guardando en la carpeta del proyecto y no en la ruta desde donde estoy cogiendo el fichero. La idea es sobrescribir estos cambios.

```py
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32
import time
import getpass
import openpyxl

xlApp  = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xw.Book(r'ruta\fichero.xlsx')
wb.api.RefreshAll()
time.sleep(40)
xlApp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb.save("ruta\fichero.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Si estás en Windows deberías usar una ruta como esta ``C:\\ruta\\fichero.xlsx`` , creo que ahí está el problema.

Comment: o en su defecto, para que tu codigo funcione en cualquier sistema operativo deberias usar: `os.path.join('ruta','fichero.xlsx')`. Puedes pasarle cuantos argumentos quieras a esta funcion, ejem: `os.path.join('mnt','d','users','currentuser','desktop','proeycto','ruta','file.txt')`

Comment: he utilizado ambos métodos y por fin ha funcionado: path = os.path.normpath(r'ruta\\fichero.xlsx')
os.path.join('ruta', 'fichero.xlsx')
wb.save()